# What is the right way of doing javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

Asuming:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.move = function() {
  // move
};
function Rabbit() {
  // do rabbit stuff
}
```

I've seen people do inheritance differently. See code below, but Which is the correct way? They all seem to work the same way

```
Rabbit.prototype = Rabbit.prototype;
// or
Rabbit.prototype = Rabbit.prototype.__proto__;
// or
Rabbit.prototype = new Rabbit();
```

Comment: None of those alternatives makes any sense, I don't think. The first one doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you actually mean `Animal` instead of `Rabbit` on the right hand side? (still, none of those would be correct)